# FreeBSD: Put Server Files on Its Own Partition/Slice

Tags: partition, freebsd, system-installation, webserver

When installing FreeBSD v9, can I specify that a particular partition/slice have /var/www/ as a mount point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!

Give a look at: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/bsdinstall-partitioning.html#bsdinstall-part-review

That's what you're going to face when you'll install FreeBSD 9 and later.

You can decide where to mount single partitions, so yes, you should be able to mount a certain partition as /var/www

Is this helpful? If not, I can give a longer reply.

Comment: Thanks! I see you are new here. Welcome to StackExchange! Once you get the privilege, do not forget to upvote questions/answers that you like or that helped you. If you read the "About" page located on the top of this page, you will get a badge once you reach the bottom. That page is helpful.